# Eclipse Code Formatting

Tags: eclipse, adobe, dreamweaver, code-formatting

I have switched my development environment from Adobe DreamWeaver to Eclipse, and I had one question regarding the Eclipse environment. Whenever I copy and paste sections of code from one area of a script to another, often times the indenting isn't consistent with the surrounding code.

Is there a way I can indent/outdent large sections of code instead of having to manually correct them on a line-by-line basis?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What language are you using? For java, the formatter is amzaing, but formatting support is on a language-by-language basis. If the language does have formatter support, you can configure eclipse to format every time you save - now I save religiously just so that all my code looks neat :)

Comment: I downloaded the PHP Developers package, which also supports JS, CSS, etc... I also use the Adobe Flash Builder plugin, which is an XML like format, as well as ActionScript 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To indent or outdent a section of code, you can select the entire section and then press tab or shift-tab.

Answer (score 0):

I do Java development in Eclipse and to format code I select it and press Ctrl + Shift + F. It is also available from Menu -> Source -> Format.

Note that I am working with Eclipse 3.5.1, but I dont think this key combination will change for other versions.

Comment: Thanks for the input, Omer. I tried using the suggested key-stroke and it formatted it very strangely. Is there a way I can just do indentation on selected areas?

Comment: You can change tab width, in Menu -> Window -> Preferences -> General -> Editors ->Text Editors. But I dont know if that is what you are looking for.